# Comparing two multi-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, uid

My lists looks like this (those numbers are UIDS):

```
sysusers = [['user1'],[7972],
           ['user2'],[2121],
           ['hacker'],[2132]
           ['hacker2'],[1232]]
users = [['user1'],[7972],
        ['user2'],[2121]]
```

I want to take the difference of those two lists and output it in a list similar to this:

```
badusers = [hacker,
           hacker2]
```

Comment: Ok so do that then

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and what doesn't work, that way we can help you

Comment: `users = [['user1'][7972],['user2'][2121]]` is not valid syntax

Comment: @MooingRawr Not true.

Comment: In relation to what @MooingRawr said, you might want to use an `array` of `dictionaries` instead to better store your data. So something like: `users = [{ 'uid' : 7972, 'username' : 'user1' }, { 'uid' : 2121, 'username' : 'user2' }]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann In theory it's valid syntax if the UIDs are slices (e.g.
 `['astring'][3]) == 'r'`) but, even if you weren't getting IndexErrors left and right, you'd end up with a list of strings (e.g. `['u','i,'h']`). It's puzzling why you chose this type of data structure when, say, sets of tuples or a dictionary {UID: name} would serve you much better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Whooper nitpick: that's a *list* not an array.

Comment: @offbyone It's valid syntax, period. Not just in theory (what is that even supposed to mean?). And huh? It's puzzling why I chose this type of data structure? I didn't.

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Thanks for the correction @juanpa.arrivillaga :D

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think the _It's puzzling why you chose this type of data structure_  part is addressed to OP. And yes it definitely is a valid syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is the way the lists are structured.

There needs to be a comma separation between each list.

```
sysusers = [['user1'],[7972],
           ['user2'],[2121],
           ['hacker'],[2132],
           ['hacker2'],[1232]]

users = [['user1'],[7972],
        ['user2'],[2121]]
```

Once this is correct, accessing the data you require is simple.

```
goodusers = []

for i in users:
    for j in i:
        for k in sysusers:
            for l in k:
                if l == j:
                    goodusers.append(k)

badusers = [x for x in sysusers if x not in goodusers]
print(badusers)

[['hacker'], [2132], ['hacker2'], [1232]]
```

Comment: my bad, in my actual code there is comma separation

Comment: Did my answer help or have I misread the question lol.. .....also.  update the question with commas